# How to remove the domain of variables in result relation?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

this is my relation and it returns me xP [Element] Integers. I do not want any kind of these information. for example, I just need to see for every relation, yp-> x+1 - xp , thanks

```
Simplify[Solve[
   Exists[{xPP, yPP, zPP}, Element[{x, y, z}, Integers], 
    xPP == 2 + x && yPP == 1 + y && zPP == 2*(2 + x) && 
     xP == xPP - yPP && yP == yPP && zP == zPP]], 
  Element[{x, y, z}, Integers]] /.  ConditionalExpression :> And

{{y -> 1 + x - xP && xP \[Element] Integers, 
  yP -> 2 + x - xP && xP \[Element] Integers, 
  zP -> 2 (2 + x) && xP \[Element] Integers}}
```

Comment: Will `Simplify[Solve[...],Element[{x,y,z,xP},Integers]]` remove the `xP \[Element] Integers]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

@Bill answer is right and thanks.

```
Simplify[Solve[...],Element[{x,y,z,xP},Integers]]
```